# What is the probability of an item belonging to 1 of 3 different sized hands where hands are drawn from overlapping sets?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Given 3 different possibly overlapping sets of unique items, 3 players can pick n amount of items from each set to make their hand.

An example of 3 overlapping sets of unique items and the correlating closing relation
[image: An example of 3 overlapping sets of unique items and the correlating closing relation]

In this case, the red player picks 4 from the red circle, which contains items that blue and green can also pick from. If more than 1 person could pick the same item, I know that the total would be the product of the 3 combinations, but because only 1 person can own a particular item, I know I have to subtract from that total to get the actual allowed total number of combinations.

I was able to solve this with 2 sets/players from the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392749/probability-of-selecting-identical-objects-from-2-partially-overlapping-groups)
The only difference from my question and the post is that in my case, I'm looking for all combinations where there is NO overlap and I'm trying to do it with 3 people instead of 2.

It seems to me like this is exponential time complexity? If worse comes to worse, I'm considering writing a program that calculates every single combination and then using that collection of combinations, determining how many result in a particular item belonging to a particular person.

I'm hoping this is solvable with some math though so that I don't have to write that code. I've looked into Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. I've looked up Multisets? I have no real math background and I have no one else to really ask. I can provide more information/examples too if needed.